# Solve T(n) = T(n-1) + n^4 by Substitution Method

Tags: algorithm, substitution, recurrence

```
Can someone please help me with this ?
```

**Use substitution method to solve it.** T(n) = T(n-1) +n^4
    Explanation of steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Steps:
1. Get a book or use Google.
2. Understand what recurrence relations are.
3. Understand ways to solve recurrence relations
4. Try solving the problem.
5. Try some values of 'n' and check if the solution works.
6. Goto step 1.

Comment: thanks! that really helped me.

Comment: well, I did the following things you asked me to, first, I turned some pages in my book (Introduction to Algorithms by Thomas H. Cormen) and then googled my query but  MR. Google led me to StackOverflow where people had already answered a question which was different from mine and the method which was used for solving that question was different. Let me tell you, I am not an inborn genius in recurrence relations. I tried solving  this question several times but I failed. Tomorrow is my exam, I thought StackOverflow people could help me with this, So I asked my query here.

Comment: Try to calculate T(1), T(2), T(3), T(4) and T(5). You will notice a pattern. If you don't, please update the question with how you tried to get the above, what the values were etc. Then you may get better help.

Comment: @IMP, Sorry to hear that, sadly StackOverflow isn't a place for tutoring school nor a place for someone who wants to boost his exam result in one night.  Strictly speaking, your question is not even about programming  ... So RIP to your exam :(

Answer (score 1):

```
T(1) = 1^4
T(2) = T(1) + 2^4 = 1^4 + 2^4
T(3) = T(2) + 3^4 = 1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4
...
T(n) = 1^4 + 2^4 +... + n^4 = n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1)/30
```

the proof is given by:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/calculus1/lecture/uR7YK/what-is-the-sum-of-n-4-for-n-1-to-n-k